# Django IIS and SQL with NT Authentication

Tags: sql-server, django, windows, iis-8

Good morning. I have several Django apps running in my work environment. All are running through Gunicorn on Ubuntu. I have a new app that must run on Windows for ODBC reasons. This new app is running in development mode on a Windows 10 PC. I run the dev server while logged in as a service account, it uses a trusted connection (local credentials as I understand) to query a SQL server and works perfectly. I ported this app (virtualenv and all) to a Windows Server 2012 r2 instance and run the dev server successfully from there using my domain admin credentials (again trusted_connection=yes).

I set up IIS on this server to run the app permanently and it appears to run. However, I get a django error page that says the SQL login failed for 'DOMAINNAME\SERVERNAME'.
I have tried editing my Application Pool to use the credentials of the working service account (Advanced Settings > Process Model > Identity). With this configuration I no longer see a Django error page, just Service Unavailable HTTP Error 503. I have tried 'recycling' and restarting the IIS service after the change but that has not worked.

Unfortunately, I do not have admin access to the SQL server to create or edit accounts. Is it possible to configure IIS to connect to SQL, through the app, using the service account credentials that I know work. If I were to configure the Application Pool successfully in this way should I still have the trusted connection setting in my connection string? Thanks!

Comment: Are you hosting your application via local system or network service account? If so, please set a domain user that have permission to access your database instead.

Comment: The domain user (service account) I am using has access. I run the dev server while logged in under that account and it works. The question is, how can I use that service account to run the app when running under IIS? IIS must continue to run with no one logged in. I have tried putting the credentials that work for the dev environment in the Application Pool  in production and the page does not load under that config.

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution to this?